# C# Sum of Values in a nested dictionary where value is a class Dictionary<string, Dictionary<Int16, CommonData>>

Tags: c#, .net, linq, dictionary

I have a dictionary with following format, where Value is a nested dictionary in which value is a class. I have tried various ways to flatten it, but no hope. I went through most of the related SO questions also. But couldn't find the answer.

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<Int16, CommonData>>
```

Common Data is a class.

```
    public class CommonData
    {
        public int Submitted { get; set; }

        public int Delivered { get; set; }

        public int Failed { get; set; }
    }
```

Now What I need is I need to sort the main dictionary based on the Sum of the data in the `CommonData` Class. I need to sum up `Submitted` + `Delivered` + `Failed` in the Values and sort the main dictionary according to this summed value.

How can we achieve this using LINQ. Could you help me with this. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't give some example input/output but I think your looking for something like

```
var result = yourMainDict.OrderBy(x => x.Value.Sum(v => v.Value.Delivered + v.Value.Submitted + v.Value.Failed));
```

Comment: So if it is a lengthy class, we need to sum up all properties individually? Is it possible to do single sum(), using `SelectMany()` or `Values()`.